# My mouse icon is messed on my computer

Tags: windows-7, mouse-cursor

My mouse cursor has decided to randomly display what appears to be half an 'X' whenever the resize window cursor is displayed. I have circled it in red in this image. It is driving me nuts! I am always misclicking because of it. It is cross application. I see it in everything from Chrome to a report editor.

Oddly, I took a screenshot with 'cursors on.' But the artifact is not included! So I had to take a picture with my phone.

Windows 7 64. Relatively new install (three months old or so). Any ideas how to fix/remove it?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried updating your graphics card drivers?

Comment: No, haven't tried that. I'm running integrated intel graphics though. And they are current at least as of 3 months ago. I would expect them to be quite stable.

Comment: artifact stuck in curser buffer of video card? caused by a bad previous curser? does switching to a whole new different set of cursers change anything?  If you were to look at the whole curser set your using, would that chunk be a piece of any of them? even a single layer of the bitmap of them?

Comment: It only seems to occur with the resize window cursor. I will try switching to a different cursor set and post my results. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: If that doesnt work, , more stuff.  Go to Mouse properties , in Pointers Tab, turn off "Enable Pointer Shadows" ,apply test. Same place disable "theme pointer change" apply test.  Reboot, test.  . .  Back in mouse again. Pointer Options, "turn off pointer trails", and "hide pointer when typing" and "CNTRL show", all unchecked. reboot test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that by uninstalling Synaptics mouse software for my laptop's touchpad via Add/Remove programs fixed the issue. I am very happy.

Comment: My guess based on this is that the Synaptics application installed new mouse cursors and the cursor for that particular cursor was demented. Uninstalling removed the cursor and Windows set it back to the default.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue on my laptop, also featured with Synaptics, and solved it by rotating my monitor sideways and rotating it back - or the other way around, since I use it rotated by default, which might explain the issue, according to Stuart → check [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/387809/weird-cursor-on-second-display-only/754022#754022?newreg=d033cdd057bf4b3886dbc767aa720a64).